# modifying dom elements using forEach method

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a unordered list in my html document where am trying to update each of the list elements of which there are five with text from an ajax request. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var modify = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var modifyText = document.createTextNode( request.responseText );
var modifiedElements = [].slice.call(modify);
modifiedElements.forEach(function(elem){
    console.log(elem);
    elem.appendChild(modifyText);
});
```

The problem i am having is that only the last list element is being updated. Why is that the case? Thank you.

Comment: if you are sure no other content is in there you can use `elem.innerHTML = request.responseText;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating only 1 text node, which is placed in each `li` element, resulting in moving it from the previous node.

You need to create a new node for each iteration

```js
var request = {
  responseText: 'some text'
}; //as a stub
var modify = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
[].forEach.call(modify, function(elem) {
  var modifyText = document.createTextNode(request.responseText);
  console.log(elem);
  elem.appendChild(modifyText);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is `[]` == `Array.prototype` ?

Comment: the result example html should contain the string `'some text'`

Comment: no... it is a empty array... just shortcut for using `Array.prototype.forEach()`  - we create an empty array and access the `forEach` method

Comment: it is but if the html you posted is the result it should contain the text `some text` in all the li's

Answer (score 1):

About `Node.appendChild()` method:

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document,
>   appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position. ... So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position. The Node.cloneNode() can be used to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new parent

In such case you can use `Node.cloneNode()` method:

```
var modify = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var modifyText = document.createTextNode( request.responseText );
var modifiedElements = [].slice.call(modify);
modifiedElements.forEach(function(elem){
    console.log(elem);
    elem.appendChild(modifyText.cloneNode());
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode